# Getting Values From td, input in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-forms

I'm having difficulty in getting the values from inside the table inside td and inputs. I tried to click the button and alert it but it gets undefined. How am i going to get the values from these fields? Fields are material, unit and quantity

> html

```
<tr *ngFor="let addRow of row; let rowIndex = index">
  <td>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" ngModel required #material>
      <option *ngFor="let material of materials" [value]="material.id">{{ material.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" placeholder="pcs, pack, bag etc..." #unit></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" #quantity></td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteRow(rowIndex)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<button class = "btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="onCreate(material,unit,quantity)"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Save</button>
```

> ts

```
onCreate(material, unit, quantity){
    alert(material);
  }
```

Comment: you have loop "<tr *ngFor="let addRow of row; let rowIndex = index">". for looping, material,unit and quantity reference may be generate multiple time

Comment: @TusharGhosh. Yes i remove it and it works. But i need it to add rows? How can i address this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample that you a idea to solve your problem.

Note: Be careful about javascript object reference.

//in html

```
    <tr *ngFor="let addRow of row; let rowIndex = index">
  <td>
    <select type="text" class="form-control"  required #material= 'ngModel' [(ngModel)]="data[rowIndex].material">
      <option *ngFor="let material of materials" [value]="material.id">{{ material.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" placeholder="pcs, pack, bag etc..." #unit= 'ngModel'  [(ngModel)]="data[rowIndex].unit"></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" #quantity= 'ngModel' [(ngModel)]="data[rowIndex].quantity"></td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteRow(rowIndex)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
  </td>
  <button class = "btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="onCreate(rowIndex)"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Save</button>
</tr>
```

//in ts

```
data:any = [
            {"material":"", "unit":"", "quantity":""}
            ......
            ];

onCreate(rowIndex){
    alert(data[rowIndex]);
  }
```

Comment: How can i do it? I'm putting paramters inside onCreate() function like this onCreate(material_id, project_id, quantity, unit){
    this.matService.addMat(material_id, project_id, quantity, unit)
    .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data)
          },
          error => {
             console.log(error);
          });
  }

Comment: you can try this way: <button class = "btn btn-primary float-right" onCreate(data[rowIndex].material, data[rowIndex].unit, data[rowIndex].quantity) ><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Save</button>

Comment: I'm also confused since I'm doing this in my ts         
 onCreate(material_id, project_id, quantity, unit){
    this.matService.addMat(material_id, project_id, quantity, unit)
    .subscribe(
          data => {
            alert("Added Successfully");
          },
          error => {
             console.log(error);
          });
  }

Comment: I'm want to pass several objects inside an array if i added many rows? Can you help me with this?